# Как работать с числом в котором есть буква?

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите почему число видоизменяется?

Мне нужно работать с этим числом внутри на `php` и на выводе в `js`

Но он почему то выводит такое число `8.05E-5`, как мне с таким числом работать?

Мне нужно вычитать умножать и тд

```
$qty = 0.00008050;

echo $qty; // 8.05E-5
```

Comment: для справки https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом нет ничего страшного, это число написано в [экспоненциальной записи](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C). С этими числами вы можете делать все тоже самое как с  другими числами

Comment: а на сравнение будет работать `>, <, >=, <=, ==, ===,` и другие ?

Comment: @SergeyMironov да

Comment: почти, не выйдет например преобразовать его в строку а потом сделать parseFloat

Comment: @StrangerintheQ parseFloat на JavaScript и floatval на php прекрасно понимают эту запись

Comment: @AterLux угу, спасибо, я почему-то был уверен в обратном, даже проверять не стал